# Adding ssl cert for API on device using netsh

Tags: api, ssl, https, certificate, netsh

Ive imported the certificate into windows.

Ive bound the port to the certificate using:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:13346
> certhash=3F59CB21AC9C833D7934EBBFD51CB52AAF34EC51
> appid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"

This returned a success.

My API is starting according to the logs without any internal errors.

I can telnet to my API's port.

When i browse to the URL it just times out.
I cant see anything in the windows event viewer.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @RonaldAbellano I think the issue was that the port i had registered 13346 was wrong and my app was using 13345